# Can't update nodejs with the sudo n stable trick, cannot stat error (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I try the following :

Installing npm and nodejs through apt.

Installing the latest npm version, like :

```
npm npm@install -g
```

Ending up with nodejs version 0.10 or something, and npm version 3.10.8

I try to install n throught npm, like (seems to be the answer on most forums) :

```
sudo npm cache clean -f 

sudo npm install -g n
```

Then, I try to install the crap :

```
sudo n stable
```

Get an error :

```
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/n/versions/node//bin': No such file or directory
```

etc
etc

Any ideas ? All I want is to get the latest version of nodejs.

I have tried to download the node tar, but how can I get nodejs to become the same version as node ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good manager that will help you with all node versions.
It's called `nvm`(Node version manager).

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

All install guides are on git page. I install it like this.

`curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`

`bash install_nvm.sh`

Check to see if everything installed correctly

`nvm --version`

Then when you want update node you can just do

`nvm install 6.9.1` (or any version you like)

`nvm alias default 6.9.1`

`nvm use default`

After restarting of your terminal run

`node -v` you should have 6.9.1 installed and used.

Hope this helps.